# How to change list to multimap in scala?

Tags: scala, multimap

I'm newbie in Scala, I have a list like below and want to convert into map.I have tried with MultiMap but i'm not able to achieve my goal.Any help will be appreciable.

```
object Mapis{
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val list=
        ("rcdTypCd"="Q1",
        "rcdTypCd"="W1",
        "rcdTypCd"="E1",
        "rcdTypCd"="R1",
        "rcdTypCd"="T1",
        "rcdTypCd"="Y1",
        "rcdTypCd"="U1",
        "rcdTypCd"="I1",
        "rcdTypCd"="O1",
        "rcdTypCd"="P1")
    //list type is Iterable[string]
    val multiM = new HashMap[String, Set[String]] with MultiMap[String, String]
      list.foreach { case (key, value) => multiM.addBinding(key, value) }
    println(multiM)
    }}
```

Output should be like below

```
   val mymap= Map(rcdTypCd->Q1,
    rcdTypCd->W1,
    rcdTypCd->E1,
    rcdTypCd->R1,
    rcdTypCd->T1,
    rcdTypCd->Y1,
    rcdTypCd->U1,
    rcdTypCd->I1,
    rcdTypCd->O1,
    rcdTypCd->P1)
```

Whenever i will call the key(rcdTypCd), it will prints all the corresponded values

```
println(key)
```

it prints all the values like below

```
Q1,W1,E1,R1,T1,Y1,U1,I1,O1,P1
```

Comment: Can you explain better the types of the rcdTypCd and the values

Comment: @dirceusemighini, rcdTypCd is alpha numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `MultiMap` mutable collection will help you:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable{ HashMap, Set, MultiMap }

// I assumed you have a list of tuples
val list = List(
  "rcdTypCd" -> "Q1",
  "rcdTypCd" -> "W1",
  "rcdTypCd" -> "P1"
)

val mm = new HashMap[String, Set[String]] with MultiMap[String, String]
list.foreach { case (key, value) => mm.addBinding(key, value) }

println(mm) // Map(rcdTypCd -> Set(Q1, W1, P1))
```

Just be careful with the imports, as you need mutable collections here. And be sure to check out the [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/MultiMap.html).

Comment: Andrei T,thanks for you replay, I'm getting this Error:(X, X) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : (T1, T2)
 required: String
  sl.foreach { case (key, value) => mm.addBinding(key, value) }

Comment: Could you please edit your current code? Or post it here? I need to see it to help you

Comment: You actually got wrong the list definition, as that's not a valid syntax. Try something like `val list = List("A" -> "B", "C" -> "D")`. Or if your list has strings like in `List("A=B", "C=D")` then do `list.map(_.split("=", 2)).foreach { case Array(key, value) => multiM.addBinding(key, value) }`

Answer (score 0):

Use foldLeft if you want to do it functionally:

```
  import scala.collection.immutable.Map

  val original = List("sd=sdf")

  original.foldLeft( Map[String, String]() ) ( (accumulatedValue: Map[String, String], str: String) => {
    val array: Array[String] = str.split("=")
    val newMap: Map[String, String] = accumulatedValue + (array(0) -> array.last)
    newMap
  })
```

As the name implies, `foldLeft` folds the list into a single value starting from the left side of the list.

`foldLeft` is a curried function. The first parameter that you pass in is called the seed and you can think of this as the starting point for your fold. The second parameter is a function that takes two parameters (the accumulated value throughout the fold and an element from the list) and returns a new value to use in the next iteration of the fold. Types are spelled out to make it clearer.

Comment: I have tried above set of code and it returns only one key and value like this Map(rcdTypCd->U1).